# AWS Elastic Search migration from 1.5 to 5.5

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-elasticsearch

I was using elastic search 1.5 and now needs to migrate to 5.5. However there's no direct way supported by AWS. I'm using cloudwatch streaming support for elastic search to feed events.

Now only the new events get feed in to elastic search. I'm thinking of following steps to migrate.

1. Create a new ES domain with 5.5.
2. Do a onetime import of existing cloudwatch logs.
3. Change the ES domain endpoint in the lambda function to point to the new ES domain.
4. Drop the old ES domain.

Is there a way to achieve step 2 in the process? Or is there any better way of achieving this migration?

Comment: did you check this doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-version-migration.html

Comment: @CasperSL yes I did.

Answer (score 2):

Your strategy looks good to me. We have done this ES migration in past. Only thing you need to remember is that 1.5 to 5.5 is not a straight forward migration. There are lots of code changes also involved. Lots of classes are not even available in 5.5.

For import; you might have to write a custom export and importer.